# Is $T(x) = Ax$ always true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $T:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is a linear transformation and A is some matrix for T with respect to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$, is $T(x)=Ax$ where $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ always true?

Comment: How about the zero vector? There may be no other $x$.

Comment: Please make a clear distinction between a linear transform $T$ (which is a special function between vector spaces) and a matrix which is a representation of some linear transform $U$ wrt to two fixed (finite) bases for these vector spaces. Is $A$ a matrix related to $T$ in any way? If they're completely arbitrary, we can just say $x=0$ is the only guaranteed such vector.

Comment: Or do you mean to ask "Is there always a matrix $A$ such that $T(x)=Ax$?"

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ah yes sorry I meant A being a matrix for T with respect to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: @Arthur I was thinking more along the lines of if $T(x)=Ax$ holds for all vectors $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: That's what the matrix is for. Given $T$, we fix two bases (domain, and range), here the two standard bases of $\Bbb R^n$. Then write $T(e_i)$ as a linear combination of the standard basis vectors and use that represention as the $j$-th column of a matrix $A$. Then linearity ensures that $T(x) = Ax$ whenever we write $x$ as a column vector wrt the standard basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if $A$ is *some* matrix, but rather if $A$ is *the* matrix for $T$ rel some bases, then yes, $T(x)=Ax\,,\forall x\in V$.

You can see this by writing $v$ in terms of the first basis, and then using linearity.

Why don't we try the standard basis in $\Bbb R^2$.  Then any $v=(v_1,v_2)=v_1e_1+v_2e_2$.  So if $A$ is the matrix whose columns are $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$, in terms of the standard basis, then we get $T(v)=T(v_1e_1+v_2e_2)=v_1T(e_1)+v_2T(e_2)=v_1Ae_1+v_2Ae_2=A(v_1e_1+v_2e_2)=Av$.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you want the equality to hold $\forall \; x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.) This is only true if $A$ is the matrix for $T$ with respect to the same standard basis which you have also considered while writing your $x$ as a column vector.

Comment: Are there two different standard basis ?

Comment: If you fix order, then there is only one. Otherwise, it's a permutation. But that is not important. The only thing that matters is the basis w.r.t. which $A$ is matrix for $T$ and w.r.t. which the vector $x$ is written as a column (i.e. it's components) should be the same.

Comment: IMO, that's implicit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by linearity of the transformation.

$$T((x_1,x_2,\cdots x_d))=x_1T((1,0,\cdots0)+x_2T((0,1,\cdots0)+\cdots x_dT((0,0,\cdots1)$$

and this matches

$$A\,(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_d)^T=x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\cdots x_da_d,$$

where $a_k=A(0,0,\cdots 1,\cdots0)$ is a column vector of $A$.